# Would a removable door frame improve the safety of a fuselage door plug design?

Tags: aircraft-design

The 737 fuselage door plug has the dubious distinction of failing in the same direction it was designed to be installed or removed ... from the outside.

An analogous design is mounting a truck tire and rim onto an axle with ***many*** bolts, that are carefully torqued to spec.  Steering systems take it further with **castle** nuts, with a cotter pin through the bolt to prevent the nut from turning.

In housing construction, carpenters build **frames** to hang doors from.

Which leads me to wonder:

1. Could they not build a beveled frame for the plug so the door could only be *pulled* to the inside *even if all bolts failed*?

2.  Would more bolts (like 14) make the existing design safer?

The "bevel" frame could be changed out with a regular door frame as needed.

Pressure differential between cabin and outside would make the beveled door almost impossible to open at altitude.

Some numbers:

The plug 6 foot × 2.5 foot × 12 inch × 12 inch = 2160 inches$^2$

Pressure. 8000 feet:   11 psi

Pressure 40000 feet :  3 psi

2160 inches$^2$ × (11-3 psi) = 17280 lbs

That door ain't moving.

Comment: What would prevent the *beveled frame* from separating from the fuselage?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri  One possible design (as the bevel would be to the inside) might be to put a flange or a lip on the inner edge and have like 30 bolts all the way around to the door frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of main doors and most service doors are the same type of "plug" door. They aren't true plugs as in a cork stopper, that has to back away to be opened. Some main doors and most emergency exits are made that way (like a cork), but they have to move inward and rotate to be opened (or rotated and tossed out in the case of an emergency exit), but main doors designed to open outward after moving in and turning are less common now. Service doors are typically lift-and-out plug doors and will use a large swing arm to let the door move out and completely outside of the way so that servicing platforms can back right up to the door sill.

These doors are still considered plug doors because cabin pressure still pushes them against the fuselage structure, but it's in the form of stop fittings that can be cleared by lifting the door, so the door structure doesn't have to be wider than the opening and it can open straight out once lifted.

When I look at the pictures of the "door plug" on the 737, it looks like just a version of the normal operable door that swings straight out and down after being lifted, but which is installed with blocker bolts in the upper roller tracks to prevent the lifting mechanism from being operated. Even with the blocker bolts missing, it's a mystery how the door could open on its own with one or two thousand pounds pushing on it as soon as the airplane pre-pressurizes during takeoff, increasing to about 5 tons at 14000 ft. When it's not lifted clear, it works the same as a cork style plug door, with cabin pressure pushing the door against the fuselage structure, except the loads are going through overlapping lug fittings spaced along the frame, instead of the entire door perimeter.

Anyway, there seems to be more to this story than meets the eye.

Comment: OK the "bolts" seem to act more as "cotter pins" rather than directly being pressure loads.  But only 4 of them?  One might consider bolting the stop pads too (once they are overlapped after the door drops in).

Comment: There will be lugs all down the side of the door frame. The bolts in question are blocking the exit of rollers from L shaped guide tracks at the top.  There is some evidence the bolts holding the tracks themselves were loose. I can see that if that happened and the door was able to jiggle up and down when unpressurized, the load bearing cleats might be just overlapping slightly when pressure is applied, and it hung on for a while until boom. All to say there's nothing wrong with the basic concept, as it's used with success on most pressurized doors.

Comment: that makes sense. Upon further review of the design it looks like there are 2 hinged pins at the bottom and a drop in guide on top with the 4 bolts preventing upward movement of the door.  This would make the top guides critical.  Absolutely.  Even though the bottom bolts hold the door to the pins ... this one hurts.

Comment: The main airstair door on the CJRs isn't a plug at all. It's just a door with big pins that stick out into the frame at 6 places, a piano hinge at the bottom and a kind of retainer cam at the top. When pressurized, the shear load on the pins makes it impossible to move the mechanism to try to open it. When open, the door actually rests on the ground with a little roller foot thing that flips out.

Answer (score 1):

Would it improve the safety, maybe.

Many aircraft doors are indeed ["plug type"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8380/how-does-the-hinge-mechanism-of-plug-type-pressure-doors-work) doors for this reason and must first be opened into the airframe, rotated a bit then can be pushed out of the airframe. However the critical part of this design is that it provides a neat failure option on *something that ultimately needs to open and close*.

[Door plugs](https://www.kgw.com/article/news/local/airplane-plug-door-door-plugs-explainer/283-2f5d3371-fec8-409c-86e4-88658d0acd02) on the other hand are panels that are intended to fill an area where a door *would have been* and thus generally don't open and close and can rely on other methods of mounting that may make servicing easier. In aviation weight is a considerably important factor when designing parts, as such cap pieces like the door plug in question will be designed to operate correctly and be as light as possible. There are plenty of places where redundancy *can be added* to aircraft in the name of safety but one must understand the implications of over complicating a design.

There are pressurized airframes out there that utilize non plug type doors with other locking mechanisms and have flow [quite successfully for an enormous number of flight hours](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27763/what-fail-safe-protections-exist-to-prevent-non-plug-type-cabin-doors-opening-in) indicating that there are ways to safely design a door plug that can be installed from the outside.

Comment: From your reference:  door plugs are designed to permanently seal off optional exits door openings.  Why not do it right? (But I do agree with your last sentence).

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni No, not ***permanently***. The point of the plug is so that the plugged opening can later be converted to a door, if the seating configuration is changed so that the extra 2 exits are needed. The plug is *fairly* permanent in that it isn't expected to move or be opened for a long time, but the option to swap it over to a door is there. Which is why it isn't, for instance, welded into place with everything in contact where it needs to be.

Comment: @RalphJ that's the mystery to me.  A beveled design would be even easier to remove if the aircraft was re-configured.